# C# Foreach (var) statement only returning single character and not whole string

Tags: c#, foreach

Arrow is the start of the issue. When returning the object and pulling out the Site ID's it works up until case 10. Once it hits that it only pull "1" from rows then goes back around and pulls the "0". The *rows[i][4].ToString()* will pull the whole string if I just point to the direct object *rows[0][4.ToString()]*, but when I'm running through it with **var item in** it only pulls single characters. I've tried actual words from columns and it does letter by letter.

I'm not sure if theres something small I'm missing or if this just isn't possible with the switch case, or how I'm doing it.

This is my first real project so excuse the mess of code. Thanks for any insight in advance!

```
        {
            string connectionString =
                "User=***;" +
                "Password=***;" +
                "Database=server:D:Site.FDB;";

            FbConnection myConnection = new FbConnection(connectionString);

            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();

                String sql = "Select f_StatusCode(s.status) status,  count(si.qty) total, s.logdate, i.reportcategory, s.site locationid, sa.sitename " +
                "From " +
                "V_item i " +
                "Inner join v_SaleItems si on " +
                "i.objid = si.item " +
                "inner join v_sale s on " +
                "s.objid = si.saleid " +
                "Inner join v_Site sa on " +
                "sa.id = s.site " +
                "where i.objid in ('606297', '606552', '606590', '49501440', '49501448', '49501680', '609015', '609014') and f_StatusCode(s.status) in ('C:PW') and s.site = si.site and " +
                "s.terminal <> 3500036 and " +
                "i.reportcategory in ('500027') and s.logdate = 'TODAY' GROUP BY locationid, i.reportcategory,  s.logdate, i.itemtype, s.status, sa.sitename";
                FbCommand com = new FbCommand(sql, myConnection);
                FbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                {

                        {
                            var currentTotal = 0;
                            var rows = new List<object[]>();
                            i = 0;
                           **while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                var columns = new object[dr.FieldCount];
                                dr.GetValues(columns);
                                rows.Add(columns);
             ===>           foreach (var item in (rows[i][4].ToString()))**
                            { 
                                    switch (item.ToString())
                                    {
                                        case "2":
                                            northCountLbl.Text = rows[i][1].ToString();
                                            currentTotal += Int32.Parse(northCountLbl.Text);
                                            currentCountLbl.Text = currentTotal.ToString();
                                            i++;
                                            break;

                                        case "3":
                                            ceresCountLbl.Text = rows[i][1].ToString();
                                            currentTotal += Int32.Parse(ceresCountLbl.Text);
                                            currentCountLbl.Text = currentTotal.ToString();
                                            i++;
                                            break;

                                        case "10":
                                            riverbankCountLbl.Text = rows[i][1].ToString();
                                            currentTotal += Int32.Parse(riverbankCountLbl.Text);
                                            currentCountLbl.Text = currentTotal.ToString();
                                            i++;
                                            break;
                                        case "11":
                                            atwaterCountLbl.Text = rows[i][1].ToString();
                                            currentTotal += Int32.Parse(atwaterCountLbl.Text);
                                            currentCountLbl.Text = currentTotal.ToString();
                                            i++;
                                            break;

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }                           
                }
                dr.Close();
                myConnection.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(er.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're doing `foreach` over a string. Each item will therefore be a character. `"10"` will yield two items: `"1"` and `"0"`. It *looks* like you don't need the foreach at all. Simply `var item = rows[i][4].ToString()`

Comment: If you have only one value in `row[i][4]` why you need to use foreach there?

Comment: don't use foreach then, instead `item = row[i][4].ToString();`

Comment: You guys are amazing, that was it. I understand why it wasn't working with the foreach now and it's working as it should now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully at this code:

```
foreach (var item in (rows[i][4].ToString()))
```

specifically, this expression:

```
rows[i][4].ToString()
```

That looks up the 5th (0-index) column in the current row, and converts the value to a string. You then use `foreach` on that that string value. *Of course* `foreach()` on a string iterates over individual characters. What else would you expect?

I'm not sure what you want the code to do here, so I'll have to make a couple different suggestions:

1. Get rid of the `foreach` completely. Keep the switch in the loop body. You're already iterating through the rows with `while (dr.Read())`.
2. Change the `foreach` to look like this: `foreach (var item in rows[i].Select(c => c.ToString()))`. This will loop through each of the columns in the result set.

Comment: Thanks Joel, that worked perfectly. And I appreciate the initial part of getting me to look at it and thinking about what it was actually doing. It makes total sense now and I understand what was going on...

Answer (score 1):

Other already gave you the answer to your question: you looping a string, which is in fact an array of chars, you are getting each of the items in that array.

So, as others suggested, `item = row[i][4].ToString();` would be the best approach to achieve what you want.

Now, in other parts of your code:

- your `string sql` variable is assigned from a series of string concatenation operations which are very bad (memory wise). Maybe you could use a [Verbatim multiline string literal](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx#literals), [String.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd(v=vs.110).aspx)
  or [StringBuilder object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Put the connection object inside of a `using` statement
- Same for the `FbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();`, inside of a `using` statement
- With the `using` statements you wouldn't need to `Close();`
- If you don't like the idea of the `using` statements, at least put your `Close();` in a `finally` block before the final `catch`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'll look into those options for the  string sql, its a pretty basic app, but knowing more about these will only help in the future and improve this app. Thank you sir!

Comment: The string concatenation for the sql variable is fine in this scenario. Some compiler versions will even optimize it all away, because they are all constants. You just don't want to be doing this in a tight loop.

Comment: "Some" is the key here. Also, String concatenation using the + operator is not really a good/advantageous practice over any of the options given... But I understand your point and it might not be so bad (just 13 objects created by my count)

Comment: Even compiler versions that don't make this go away entirely and put them all in the same constant will still group them as an array and use String.Concat()